# Upload laravel project inside a folder in public_html on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting, shared

My project frontend is indifferent technology and cms is in laravel so on shared hosting I want to upload laravel project in particular named folder like cms so my routes will be something like/cms/XXX and frontend will in root folder like public_html so how can I do this ?

Tried to create a folder named cms and then upload laravel project in that but didn't work

Comment: You have two repositories/projects: 1. `frontend` (a web page?) and 2. `backend` (CMS). You need to host both projects on the same server using the public_html directory. You have one domain (for example - `example.com`) and you want the frontend to work as usual at `example.com`, while the backend (CMS) should be accessible via `example.com/cms/`, correct?

To achieve this, we need to know what HTTP server you are using (nginx, Apache, etc.). Do you have access to the HTTP server configuration? May be you are using some hosting panel (Plesk, hPanel) for managing the server and websites?

Comment: Apache server I am using and hosting panel is cpanel

Comment: Faster and more CPanel way is create the subdomain (cms.example.com) as I see from CPanel documentation - https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360052780313-How-to-create-a-subdomain it simple and not required advance technical knowledge. Bu in case you need exactly `example.com/cms` and subdomains is unsuitable
 you need to customize Apache config (https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/advanced-apache-configuration/,) check this topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/956543/apache-virtual-hosts-map-different-paths-of-the-same-domain-or-ip-to-differe

Answer (score 0):

Follow this one :D

Connect to your ftp or whatever you use to get to hosting.

- Make folder (for example) "laravelProject" in root (above public_html)
- Now go to your local project and zip everything except the public folder
- Transfer zipped/compresed file to your hosting in "laravelProject" folder and you can either use ssh or terminal of the hosting and `unzip or unrar` that file there
- Now go to public_html and transfer files from public over there
- Go to index.php and change paths instead of `/../something` to `/../laravelProject/something`

There you go, enjoy

Quick note: You can zip public folder too and then using command line move that to other folder and move files outside of public folder etc etc but this above written is easier :)

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: @KratiSharma you did not do something right :D 

Describe me what you did? Which error you got? anything?